# Reload/change application yml values in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, health-check

I have implemented custom health check and trying to validate the database down scenario.

So, I want to change the datasource url/username/password from application yml and validate without restarting the server / without changing any config on DB.

Is there any easy option available to simulate this scenario and validate?